# php - Database value display in multiple table cell based on category

Tags: php, mysql

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Sr.</td>    
        <td>Body</td> 
        <td>Material</td>
        <td>Elastomer</td>                                       
    </tr>  
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=$quantity_sum_show;$i++){?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>
```

Let us assume the variable `$quantity_sum_show` value as 8.

From the above table, `Body,Material,Elastomer` row field values are getting from database. **I need to display the values based on the category in the table cells.**
Below is the sql query to fetch `hno_count, hno`, but confused how to display it in the table based on the category field.

Sql query:

```
select hno_count, hno, category from hnos
```

Sql Result:

```
| hno_count | hno   | category |
| -------- | -------| -------- |
| 4        | hno1   | Body     |
| 1        | hno2   | Body     |
| 3        | hno3   | Body     |
| 3        | Mhno1  | Material |
| 2        | Ehno1  | Elastomer|
```

Example: In the above result table as we can see, there are three rows with 4,1,3 respectively for the Body category. **What I'm expecting to display in the table is for the starting 4 rows of Body field, the heat no(hno1) need to display. For fifth row(hno2) need to display and for the next 3 rows(hno3) need to display.**

FYI, it's not mandatory that sum of all hno_count should be the $quantity_sum_show value, but the sum of hno_count will not be greater than the $quantity_sum_show value.

Expected Output:

```
| Sr. | Body H No | Material | Elastomer |
| --- | ----------| --------| ---------  |
| 1   | hno1      | Mhno1   |  Ehno1     |
| 2   | hno1      | Mhno1   |  Ehno1     |
| 3   | hno1      | Mhno1   |            |
| 4   | hno1      |         |            |
| 5   | hno2      |         |            |
| 6   | hno3      |         |            |
| 7   | hno3      |         |            |
| 8   | hno3      |         |            |
```

Comment: `$quantity_sum_show` how do you calculate this?

Comment: That's a product quantity count. It's using just to create the rows in the for loop.

Comment: How many categories do you have? It it a fixed list?

Comment: yes . Fixed list. Maximum 10 categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question your input data looks like this:

```
$raw_data = [
    [ 4, "hno1",  "Body"],
    [ 1, "hno2",  "Body"],
    [ 3, "hno3",  "Body"],
    [ 3, "Mhno1", "Material"],
    [ 2, "Ehno1", "Elastomer"]
];
```

So the first thing we need to do is expand that data into a format which we can iterate over...

```
$table_data = [];

foreach($raw_data as $item){
    for($i = 0; $i < $item[0]; $i++){
        $table_data[$item[2]][] = $item[1];
    }
}


// Output of: print_r($table_data);
/*
Array
(
    [Body] => Array
        (
            [0] => hno1
            [1] => hno1
            [2] => hno1
            [3] => hno1
            [4] => hno2
            [5] => hno3
            [6] => hno3
            [7] => hno3
        )

    [Material] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mhno1
            [1] => Mhno1
            [2] => Mhno1
        )

    [Elastomer] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ehno1
            [1] => Ehno1
        )

)
*/
```

Next we need to know how many rows of data there are...

```
$row_count = count(max($table_data));
```

Then we can loop through the result set and output the data in the format intended...

```
for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++){
    $row = $i + 1;
    echo "<tr><td>{$row}</td>";
    foreach($table_data as $column){
        $field = $column[$i] ?? NULL;
        echo "<td>{$field}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>hno1</td><td>Mhno1</td><td>Ehno1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>hno1</td><td>Mhno1</td><td>Ehno1</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>hno1</td><td>Mhno1</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>hno1</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>hno2</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>hno3</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>hno3</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>hno3</td><td></td><td></td></tr>


// Without markup

1  hno1  Mhno1  Ehno1
2  hno1  Mhno1  Ehno1
3  hno1  Mhno1
4  hno1  
5  hno2  
6  hno3  
7  hno3  
8  hno3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can you plz explain this logic? for($i = 0; $i < $item[0]; $i++){
        $table_data[$item[2]][] = $item[1];
    }

Comment: @ubs0305 No problem: `$item` relates to each "row" of the original array. Therefore `0, 1, & 2` relate to the "columns" of that array. So the code you referenced loops through the number of times referenced in the first column of the original array(`$item[0]`; e.g. 4 for the first iteration). It then adds the "value" (`$item[1]`; e.g. hno1) to the correct category (`$item[2]`; e.g. Body) in the newly generated array